# Cannot boot Windows 10 after disabling Secure Boot in BIOS (BitLocker recovery)

Tags: windows, thinkpad, bitlocker

Using a Thinkpad P43s laptop

As part of debugging a grub2 boot menu issue, I went BIOS and disabled "Secure Boot". After fixing my grub2 boot menu problem, I can no longer boot Windows 10. I get to a screen asking for a key for Bitlocker recovery.

I have tried to enable Secure Boot again from BIOS, but I still get to the same Bitlocker message.

I have never installed or BitLocker or need that.

Is there any way to get out of this problem, or do I need to buy a new harddrive?

**UPDATE**

I can confirm the laptop came prebaked with Bitlocker enabled. I did at no point enable this myself. I ended up deleting the windows partition from an Ubuntu live usb drive, reinstalled windows 10 from scratch and was never asked for enabling Bitlocker or backup any Bitlocker key. Going to the settings I windows now I can also see that Bitlocker is disabled.

Conclusion: Lenovo enables this when you buy their laptops with windows 10 installed and because of this I just lost all my data.

Answer (score 2):

> I have never installed or BitLocker or need that.

You might not have realized it, but BitLocker was indeed enabled, this is evident by the fact you are being asked for the BitLocker recovery key.  There is no other explanation for the behavior you describe.

> Is there any way to get out of this problem or do I need to buy a new hard drive?

There is no way to bypass the requirement for the recovery key at this point.  This requirement for the Recovery Key is a security feature of BitLocker.

If your local account was connected to a Microsoft Account, there is a chance your recovery key, can be recovered by going to [BitLocker recovery keys](https://account.microsoft.com/devices/recoverykey?refd=support.microsoft.com).  **If your account was not connected to a Microsoft Account, and that page does not display the device in question, sadly there is no way to access your current Windows installation.**

Comment: I would like to understand the reason this answer was downvoted.  If this answer isn’t helpful I would like edit it, to resolve that problem.